# Prove $\phi:(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}\to\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_n)$ such that $[x]\mapsto \phi_{[x]}([t])=x[t]$ is an isomorphism

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism, automorphism-group

I want to prove $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}\cong \text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_n)$ so

(1) I proved $f_s:G\to G $ such that $g\mapsto sg=g+\overset{s}{\dots}+g\,$ is an automorphism on $G $.  ($\gcd(s,|G|)=1)$

(2) I proved $f:\mathbb{Z}_n\to\mathbb{Z}_n$ is an automorphis on $\mathbb{Z}_n \Leftrightarrow f([1])\in (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$

Finally I  made $\phi:(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}\to\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_n)$ such that $[x]\mapsto \phi_{[x]}([t])=x[t]$ so I must prove $\phi $ is an isomorphism.

The $\gcd(|G|,x)=1$ because $x\in(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ and by (1) $\text{Im}\,\phi\in \text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_n)$

Then I proved $\phi $ is an homomorphism, let $g,h\in(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}:$
$$\phi_{[g][h]}([t])=(\phi_{[g]}\circ\phi_{[h]})([t])$$

Now I should prove $\phi $ is injective, for $g,h\in (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ such that $\phi_{[g]}([t])=\phi_{[h]}([t])$
$$g[t]=h[t]$$
$$\vdots$$
$$g=t?$$

I am not sure how prove it ..I think maybe if I multiply both sides by $[t^{-1}]$  I could get the result?

$\phi$  is surjective because if $\varphi\in \text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_n)$ then by (2) exists $g=\varphi([1])\in (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ such that $\phi_g=\varphi $ ?

Also I should prove $\phi$ is well-defined?

Any hint please?

Thank you for your help

Comment: There's a nice proof of this as **Theorem 6.5** of Gallian's *"Contemporary Abstract Algebra (Eighth Edition)"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every automorphism of the additive cyclic group ${\mathbb Z}_n$ must map $1$ to a generator $g$ of that group. It is easy to see that $g$ is a generator iff $GCD(g,n)=1$. So there is a map from ${\rm Aut}({\mathbb Z}_n)$ to ${\mathbb Z}_n^+$. On the other hand, every choice of $g$ which is coprime with $n$ gives a map $\phi$:$[k]\mapsto k[g]$ of ${\mathbb Z}_n$ to itself. It is easy to see that $\phi$ respects the operation and is a bijection. Hence $\phi$ is an isomorphism.